# uitableview ios: sorting array based on calculated distance not part of the array

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray

I have an array of points on a map.
I populate the array correctly and I make annotations for them on the map. everything is working fine.
I have another tableview with the same array, and in the "subtitle" of the cells, I calculate the distance to user and present. everything working fine.

Now,I want to sort the list in the table view, in other words I want to sort the same array by distance, lowest to highest.

The thing is that the distance is not part of the array. so how can I cross match the distance with the array, so that when I sort the distance, it takes its belonging object in the array with it and sorts the array as well?

I am fairly new to ios but I have managed to release 3 apps now, and this one is the fourth, far more complex and I think I have covered pretty good ground with making the app so far. From the mapview, to the tableview with a search controller and everything. I am only missing the sorting.

I imagine I need to add some tag or property to each object in the array and assign it to each distance in the distance array. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated :)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Assuming you have your points on the map in an NSArray called
// pointsOnMapArray and your distances in distanceArray, create a
// new mutable array to hold both.  Note, the "distances" in this
// case are stored as NSStrings.  We'll want to convert them to
// doubles before sorting them.
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Iterate over all of the points, and add a new element to the mutable
// array which is a new array containing a point and its distance.  The
// distance is converted from an NSString to an NSNumber containing a
// doubleValue.
int i;   
for (i = 0; i < pointsOnMapArray.count; i++) {
    NSArray *newItem = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [pointsOnMapArray objectAtIndex: i], [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[distanceArray objectAtIndex: i] doubleValue]], nil];
    [newArray addObject: newItem];
}

// Now, sort the new array based upon the distance in the second element
// of each array (ie, the distance).
[newArray sortUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSNumber *dist1 = [obj1 objectAtIndex:1];
    NSNumber *dist2 = [obj2 objectAtIndex:1];

    return [dist1 compare:dist2];
}];
```

Comment: This one is working lovely. but the actual comparison is strange. it is considering 256655.030734 smaller than 4947.431243 which should not be the case?

Comment: Are your distances NSNumbers containing floats?

Comment: they are NSStrings. it is like it is only comparing the first digit. i will try and make them nsnumbers. 2 min.

Comment: Oh, if they are strings, then it is doing an string compare and 256655 is less than 4947 string-wise.  Think how they'd be ordered in a library.  I'll adjust the code to convert the strings to numbers in the compare.

Comment: the thing is that i have the distances as floats. and in order to put them in an array, i need them as objects. these objects have to be nsnumbers in order to compare. after i pair them with the annotations (which thanks to you i have done successfully) the new array is location,nsnumber,location,nsnumber,etc... how do i change the whole arrays nsnumbers to nsstrings? to use them in a tableview.

By the way, I REALLY appreciate the help :) wouldnt know what to do without you guys here. I hope i will be able to give my knowledge back to people in same situations later :)

Comment: The new array is actually an array of arrays: [[location, nsnumber], [location, nsnumber], etc].  To convert the nsnumber to a string, just call stringValue on the NSNumber like this [myNSNumber stringValue];

Comment: i see. how do i access the nsnumber?
im thinking [[newArray objectAtIndex:i] objectatindex:1]?

Comment: correct, and your annotation is at [[newArray objectAtIndex: i] objectAtIndex: 0].

Comment: So your string would then be [[[newArray objectAtIndex: i] objectAtIndex: 1] stringValue]

Comment: actually it would be [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ meters", [[[newArray objectAtIndex: i] objectAtIndex: 1] stringValue]]?

damn! hehe

Comment: meters?  Don't you mean feet?  - SillyAmerican

Comment: If you're doing the string format thing, I think you can just do: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ meters",[[newArray objectAtIndex: i] objectAtIndex: 1]] because the NSNumber knows how to format itself to be included in the string.

Comment: You seem to be sharp today. the thing is that this newArray is first populated when the distance is calculated.
How can i stop the tableview from initializing until the newArray exists? is there anyway to "delay" the tableview where i can add a subview ("determining location") or something else? 
Thanks once more. your help is amazing :)

Comment: I just needed to reload the tableview data after the calculations were made... DOOOH :) Anyway thanks for your help. i am still new to stackoverflow, i have added 1 reputation and marked this as answer. is that how people do it? :) thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

try making a dictionary with distances and elements of array . then by sorting the distances , array elements can be sorted accordingly.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setObject:(array element) forKey:(correspondingDistance)];
```

Now by sorting the keys , you can sort the elements of your array accordingly.

Comment: i will try this also and get back to you :) Thanks for your reply i dont know why i didnt think of that :)